# AngularJS : controller with factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I am new to Angular and I am creating my first app right now. I have a factory in place and my controller should be pulling in data from my source, however I keep on getting this [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=SpreadsheetFactoryProvider%20%3C-%20SpreadsheetFactory%20%3C-%20appController). My factory is called SpreadsheetFactory.

I have the code for my controller below. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
(function () {

     angular
    .module('beerApp')
    .controller('appController', appController, ['$scope', 'SpreadsheetFactory']);

    function appController($scope, SpreadsheetFactory) {

        SpreadsheetFactory.getData().then( function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        });

        // $scope.brews = [];

        return data;
    }

})();
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the `SpreadsheetFactory` factory? :)

Answer (score 3):

This line is wrong:

```
.controller('appController', appController, ['$scope', 'SpreadsheetFactory']);
```

It should be:

```
.controller('appController', ['$scope', 'SpreadsheetFactory', appController]);
```